# How to get UITableViewCell position relative to screen

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, the table view is at the bottom half of the screen. I want to know the position of the selected cell relative to the entire screen, not table view.

I am using this code:

```
var cellPosition: CGRect? {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return nil }
    let rectOfCellInTableView = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
    return tableView.convert(rectOfCellInTableView, to: tableView.superview)
}
```

But the `CGRect` is always `(0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 82.0)`. Which means is the position relative to table view. `y` should be much bigger.

How can I retrieve the position of the cell relative to entire screen ?

Comment: You could use `self.tableView.convert(rectOfCellInTableView, to: UIScreen.main.coordinateSpace)` but this will cause problems for apps that run on iPad in split screen mode. Why are you converting to `tableView.superview` and not `self.view` if this is being done in a view controller?

Comment: I think its ok to use UIScreen.main.coordinateSpace because its only used on iPhone. I can't use self.view because I am not really in the viewcontroller, I have a separate object for the table view data source.

Comment: Where are you putting that snippet of code?